# Is there a way to recover a cleared notification in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, time-machine, notifications

If you `x` out a notification (or group of notifications) or click on a notification it appears to be cleared. From time to time I wish I could see or interact with it again. Either the link doesn't work properly or I just wish I hadn't cleared it out. Is there a system, app, or log file to look through to get the info? Or is there a method to start logging or collecting them for the future?

For example, I had a notification about time machine today. I suppose I cleared it out but I don't remember. Either way, I want to share the message with one of our network guys. He is attempting to set up back-up on a dedicated server.

Comment: try this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142811/46541