# How can I find the source of a Mac desktop notification?

Tags: macos, mac, notifications

I installed a trial software, NTFS for Mac, and then uninstalled it (via AppZapper). However, I am still getting occasional desktop notifications and I don't know how to get rid of these. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Oren

Comment: Clearly, AppZapper is not to be relied upon. As stated in the duplicate, the app itself has its own uninstaller.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the solution, which involves manually deleting a record from an SQL database.

Using Ralf Westphal's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443576/remove-scheduled-notifications-on-mac-osx) and Oscar Zhang's answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64629/does-the-os-x-log-notifications-from-the-notification-center) to solve my issue by editing the db file in the db2 folder. I found the app_id in the app table and then deleted it (which causes the 'app_deleted' trigger to delete the app from all the other tables). This is for Mojave. I used an SQLite editor for this ([DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)].

I will have to wait a while to confirm this works.